# If $\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}-\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}=k$, find $\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}+\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}.$ Additional data added

Tags: trigonometry, radicals

> If $\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}-\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}=k$, find $\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}+\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}$

I raised $\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}+\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}$ to the second power in order to express $k$:

\begin{align}&\color{white}=1-\cos^2x+2\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}+1+\sin^2x\\&=1-\cos^2x+\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}(2\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}-\sqrt{1+\sin^2x})\\&=1-\cos^2x+\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}2k.\end{align}

Since it doesn't give the answer, I also raised the second expression equalling $k$ to the second power. That didn't work out. The variants are:

> A)$1.5k$ B)$2k$ C)$\frac{2}{k}$ D)$-k$ E)$-\frac{1}{k}$

I have solved it in the way Fred did (having learnt from him) but as is obvious there is ***NOT*** such an answer in the variants above.

> The correct answer is E)$-\frac{1}{k}$ (according to the answer tables in the book).

How to get to that correct answer E)???

Comment: Hint: Since we only care about $\sin^2(x)$ and $\cos^2(x)$, we can assume $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are both positive. So, $\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}=\sin(x)$.

Comment: The $-$ inside the parentheses on the second line of the equality chain should be a $+$.  Even if it were a minus, that wouldn't reduce to $2k$ because the $2$ is only on the $\sqrt{1 - \cos^2 x}$.

Comment: Fred's answer is correct and easily implies answer E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obvious that $k<0$.

Let $\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}+\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}=p$.

Thus, $\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}=\frac{p-k}{2}$ and $\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}=\frac{p-k}{2}$.

Id est, $$\left(\frac{p-k}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{p+k}{2}\right)^2=1+\sin^2x-1+\cos^2x$$ or
$$-pk=1$$ or
$$p=-\frac{1}{k}.$$
Done!

Answer (score 5):

$k(\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}+\sqrt{1+\sin^2x})=(\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}-\sqrt{1+\sin^2x})(\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}+\sqrt{1+\sin^2x})=1-\cos^2x-(1+\sin^2x)=-1$.

Comment: The book says that the answer is $-k$ not $-1$. I cannot get it, is it incorrect ($-k$)?

Comment: @Tug'tekin Dividing by $k$ gives the correct answer $-\frac{1}{k}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the answer be x.Then get the question and answer in the form (a+b)(a-b) .As you know formula for this.In solving we get -1/k.